# WebView и javascript

Tags: javascript, webview, replace

Суть проблемы такова.. 
Приложение имеет WebView в которую загружается страница (в моем случае авторизация ВКонтакте )
[Ссылка](https://oauth.vk.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=353231%60&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.vk.com%2Fblank.html&response_type=token&v=&state=dsjfnsl&display=mobile&success=1)

Загружена.. окей..
javascript включен

```
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Выполняю скрипт который изменяет допустим ВКонтакте на контакт

```
public void Onclick(View v) {web.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('ВКонтакте', 'контакт');");}
```

Цель у меня на самом деле производить замены добавляя к формам id и далее кликать по кнопкам.. например заменив `<input type="text" name="code"` на `<input type="text" name="code" id="kot"`

Так вот после любой замены таким путем у меня страница получается такой, как будто не подгрузили ей css стили.. Как это предотвратить?

[image: После изменения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы заного перезаписываете весь html код страницы, т.е. слетают все js указатели, слушатели и вообще, лучше так не делать...
Если нужно добавить id к нужному полю, проще сделать так

```
web.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('code').item(0).setAttribute('id', 'kot');");
```

Comment: появилась вторая проблема при попытке выполнить таким же образом
javascript:document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value='sdsa';
Все со страницы удаляется и остается только sdsa

Comment: @Владислав, javascript:(document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value="sdsa‌")(0);